# TFS AD Group Not Authenticating

Tags: tfs, active-directory

I have a new TFS 2013 install (Basic Mode).

I added an AD Group (`MyDomain\TFSAdmins`) to the `[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Administrators` TFS group. But users in this group can't authenticate to the TFS web portal (`http://myTFSserver:8080/tfs`). Only the Administration Console User can authenticate... What am I doing wrong?

Am I missing something at the Application Tier level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did are entirely correct.You didn't missing anything at the Application Tier level.

You could try to do some trobuleshooting as below:

1.Clean IE cache,[clean TFS cilent machine chache](https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/why-and-how-to-clear-tfs-client-cache/).

2.Try to use these uers to collect TFS by VS, see if you can successfully connect it.

3.Add a AD user instead of a AD group

Comment: So I found out that TFS does not talk to AD directly on each request. It syncs on the hour (by default). So changes made in AD can take up to an hour to propagate. You can force a sync by removing and re-adding an AD Group. More info: http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/

Comment: Thanks for the useful sharing.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the "iisreset" to solve the problem. I was try to find a lot of anwsers for this problem and after thought a little more I remembered that TFS uses IIS to publish the Site. So I just use the iisreset and the users appear in the group inside TFS.